# iOS Audio visualisation using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, visualization, avplayer

I am trying to do an audio visualisation for a stream. The audio has to play in the background and currently I am playing it with an AVPlayer but I cannot get the metering from it. How can I get the metering and make the visualisation? Any suggestions?

Comment: So.... An update from you ... or ....?

Comment: See here [https://github.com/prodia/AudioVisualizer](https://github.com/prodia/AudioVisualizer)

Comment: Diana's answer helped a lot. Incase anyone else is looking for something in 2016 :)

Comment: @DianaProdan, the code is for AVAudioPlayer not AVPlayer as asked in the question.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension

Answer (score 1):

- Here you have an example with waveforms: [A cocoa audio player component which displays the waveform of the audio file](https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform)
- Here you have a [LED bar gauge](https://github.com/ChiefPilot/F3BarGauge) and another example how can be used: [ATTabandHoldAudioRecord](https://github.com/ioslovers/ATTabandHoldAudioRecord)
- Apple, also have [SpeakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) example - the code includes a LevelView .. but this Apple sample code is anything but simple to implement ...

Comment: None of these is compatible with `AVPlayer`. They all use `AVAudioPlayer` which, in turns, does not play HTTP stream.

Comment: @TonyMkenu How can I use SCWaveformView for https stream? It's not documented and I have tried in their example but it won't work.

Comment: Check this guys github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension. It might help.